# Twilio price calculation and some queries?

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

I like to know detailed price calculation for programmable video, also like to know following

What happen if I

- unpublish tracks
- track enable/disable
- connectiom failed (ice or any other reason)
- what if I do not call leave room and close the tab/browser (as socket do get break from server)

All above is related to group type room, kindly update w.r.t to price calculation in above scenarios. At what instance do really twilio stop calculating.

Comment: This is a question that is best answered by [Twilio sales](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales). I recommend you get in touch with them to discuss how the pricing works.

Comment: I believe they knew all the tech part also.

Comment: They can answer the pricing questions with respect to those technical parts, yes.

Comment: @James Z, thanks for the edit, I actually posted it via mobile, not checked the formatting.